# Find the same collection in IEnumerable

Tags: c#, database, linq, datagrid

Got a task to figure out how to update a table(`DataTable`) connected to a `database` without an `UPDATE` statement. The example I came up with is for reading alerts from a mailbox. The table will be written with ,,Alerts". If the mail body contains the word SUCCESS -> Alert turns green. If FAIL -> Alert turns red.
Scenario:
An Alert arrives that is SUCCESS, if the same Alert arrives from the same email address, with the same subject within 5 minutes but with different result(FAIL). The Alert that arrived earlier(in this case SUCCESS) is deleted.

```
public void FindUpdate(Alert newAlert, Alert matchAlert, Problem problem)
{

    //If new Alerts arrives from same email address, subject with same problem till five 5 minutes
    if (dAOAlert.GetAll().Any(x => x.Element.Equals(newAlert.Element) && x.Problem.NameOfAlert.Equals(newAlert.Problem.NameOfAlert))
        &&
        GetInterval(newAlert.Date, matchAlert.Date) > 0 && GetInterval(newAlert.Date, matchAlert.Date) <= 5)
    {
        matchAlert = dAOAlert.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Element.Equals(newAlert.Element) && x.Problem.NameOfAlert.Equals(newAlert.Problem.NameOfAlert));

       
        dAOProblem.Delete(problem);
        dAOAlert.Delete(matchAlert);
        LoadAlertGrid();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Else condition");
    }
}

//method for creating an interval
public double GetInterval(DateTime a, DateTime b)
{
    return a.Subtract(b).TotalMinutes;
}
```

My problem is that the `else statemant` is always executed even if the condition is met.

**NOTE**

Problem is not with DELTE or LoadAlertGrid() method. Both methods work

**UPDATE**
The problem is probably with `GetInterval()` method.
When first Alert arrives the returns
For first mail, sent 11:08
values

3369601

336902

For second mail, sent 11:11

values

33693,01666

33693,01666

It should return 3

Comment: *"My problem is that the else statement is always executed even if the condition is met"*. That is impossible. Maybe you think the condition is `true` but, if execution enters the `else` block and not the `if` block then it clearly isn't. Maybe you should break that logical expression in your `if` statement up into smaller parts and that would allow you to debug more easily.

Comment: `x.Element.Equals(newAlert.Element)` part looks suspicious. Did you override the `Equals` method? If not both elements should have the same reference.

Comment: You have four separate Boolean statements in that `if` statement so you should take them all out and assign each one to its own variable and use the variables in the `if` statement instead. You can then set a breakpoint on the `if` statement and see exactly which one is actually `false`. This is a part of the debugging process that you should have already done before posting here. Once you know where that issue is, you will know where to investigate further, or at least what specific question to ask us.

Comment: I have debugged the part with Equals method. I haven't override the Method btw. The problem is , I think, with the Interval part. See the example in my question

Comment: @jmcilhinney I was right, the problem is with GetInterval() method. It returns values higher than 5.

Comment: What do you mean by "values" in your updated question? The code really doesn't miscalculate the difference between two DateTimes. Not sure what you're saying here.

Comment: @GertArnold The difference between those two mails should be 3. It returns 3369601

Comment: Why? What are the actual datetime values that enter the GetInterval method? The code really doesn't get the difference wrong, you can count on that. Also, side note, you can calculate `GetInterval(newAlert.Date, matchAlert.Date)` once at the beginning of `FindUpdate`.

Comment: I have solved it. I was right, the problem was with GetInterval() method.

Comment: I really wonder what problem you found in .Net's method to subtract DateTime values. Please submit a bug report, this is serious.

Comment: @GertArnold see my update in my question. The substact method returned values 3369601 instead 3. Because first mail I sent at 11:08 and the second one 11:11. So the difference between two mails is 3 minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248505/discussion-between-petr-and-gert-arnold).

Comment: Please turn this into a [mre].  "What are the actual datetime values that enter the GetInterval method?", that must be clear.

Comment: @GertArnold I think I should post it as new question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have a hint where the problem is...

Your are dealing with minutes in your if statement logic, but in

GetInterval(newAlert.Date, matchAlert.Date)

you're basically cutting out the time part of the datetime.

Let's say you have DateTime variable 'dateAndTime' 12/06/2022 22:22 (twelfth of june 2022 22 hours and 22 minutes). When you access dateAndTime.Date, your are getting rid of the time part, therefore you have 12/06/2022 00:00.

Comment: Thats great hint. I have never met with this and it should be the solution. So what I should change? What is the inputs. The minutes of that Date?

Comment: Well, if I understand your goal correctly, you firstly need to get rid of the '.Date' (just delete it) and from there get it working ... xD I suggest you spend some time figuring out how this new information affects your code. Maybe you will fix it by yourself, maybe not. But by that time, you should have gathered more information, which you can specify here, so we can help you solve this.

Comment: The problem is that it flips the dates from 2.10. to 10.2. therefore the result is 336390.

Comment: What flips the dates? Seems like you are getting different values in parameters than you expected. Either that or I dont follow xD

Comment: Thats the problem I don't know what flips the dates too :D

Comment: It is all weird, I am just substracting two dates and wann know the difference of minutes. It seems to me as simple task