# How to find out if Date exists in an interval

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to find out if the difference between the two dates(minutes)

e.g. `Friday, 29 May 2015 11:08 AM` and `Friday, 29 May 2015 11:11 AM` is in my interval(secondDate).

```
public double GetInterval(DateTime firstDate, DateTime secondDate)
{
    return firstData.Subtract(secondDate).TotalMinutes;
}
```

It returns 33609, Expected OUTPUT: 3

If difference is more than or equal zero and is less or equal 5 do some work

```
if (GetInterval(newAlert.Date, matchAlert.Date) >= 0 && GetInterval(newAlert.Date, matchAlert.Date) <= 5){
    MessageBox.Show("true");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("false");
}
```

This is inputs from second try
firstDate: 02.10.2022 13:10:46
secondDate: 10.02.2022 13:10:46
returns 3336960

Comment: Check your inputs because that code works

Comment: What interval? I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to check whether the difference (distance) between two DateTimes is below a given threshold value?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Yes I mean that, sorry for my English. I am not a native speaker.

Comment: It works if the first date is bigger than the second date otherwise with your inputs the result is -3

Comment: If you get 33609, but expected 3, then you made wrong assumptions about your input data. Also, you seem to forget that possible differences can also be negative...

Comment: *It returns 33609* -- No, it doesn't. It returns 3. Undeniably. The difference between the DateTime values you show is 3 minutes (or -3). Show the input that returns 33609. It's not that input.

Comment: @Yeah, you all right. It is cause because wrong inputs. I will edit my question

Comment: Sorry, but I think you have to specify what it is you want to achieve. The bigger picture lets say.

Comment: I will post the inputs

Comment: @BrunoPfohl I have added another specifi input from debugg

Comment: @BrunoPfohl my bigger picture, but I want to focus on this, beacuse it solve my problem from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73924475/find-the-same-collection-in-ienumerable

Comment: I also do not know why 02.10 .. is 10.2. Both are DateTimes

Comment: Now *at last* you show the values that produce the output you claimed it's clear that you have a CurrentCulture issue. One date is parsed in US format (swapping month and day), the other in some other format.

Comment: @GertArnold Okay, so why is this happening?

Comment: Debugged showed me, that  the swap occurs in GetInterval() method.

Comment: Impossible! It only happens when dates are parsed. This, in turn, can happen in a variety of ways. e.g. when JSON is involved somewhere (web requests) or when data is read from a CSV file. Only you know the origin of these date alues.

Comment: @GertArnold Can I set cultureinfo inside GetInterval()?

Comment: @GertArnold Debugged showed me this...In WPF window in DataTable is my DateTime format right

Comment: We can't so anything for you without a [mre]. I cast the final vote to close the question for that reason (which is not the shown reason).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I have a hint where the problem is...

Your are dealing with minutes in your if statement logic, but in

```
GetInterval(newAlert.Date, matchAlert.Date)
```

you're basically cutting out the time part of the datetime.

Let's say you have DateTime variable 'dateAndTime' 12/06/2022 22:22 (twelfth of june 2022 22 hours and 22 minutes). When you access `dateAndTime.Date`, your are getting rid of the time part, therefore you have 12/06/2022 00:00.

FYI: I also posted the same answer in your other question
[Find the same collection in IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73924475/find-the-same-collection-in-ienumerable/73925442#73925442).